# Get warnings when generating ads report by calling Google AdSense API

Tags: adsense, oauth2-playground

I tried to generate a report of the ads by calling Google AdSense API but the reponse contains a warning that `Some of the requested metrics are not available for some of the ad clients used by this report.` Can you please help why I got this error? Thanks!

[sceenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iajd.png)